# What are the standard tests for determining the logical validity of syllogisms?

Tags: logic

As an exercise, I would like to write a simple program which will take as inputs three propositions (AEIO) and output true or false based on if the resulting syllogism is valid or not. Obviously, I need a rigorous understanding of exactly when a syllogism is valid. The Wikipedia article (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syllogism) mentions 256 possible syllogisms out of which 24 are valid. That opens the possibility of a hard-coded table. The following article (http://www.uky.edu/~rosdatte/phi120/lesson17a.htm) speaks of the "rule method" for determining validity but I am unclear if these are merely necessary or sufficient conditions. My question is this: what are the standard tests for syllogism validity? I would ideally like several different options to get a sense of what options are available and which are best for a computer based on different trade-offs.

Comment: [This seems to be a method](http://www.harryhiker.com/lc/docs/star.htm), but I'm not familiar with it. The ref is to H.Gensler, [A simplified decision procedure for categorical syllogisms](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.ndjfl/1093891100) (1973).

Comment: I suppose that the procedure implements the traditional "meta-theoric" rules. See [Aristotle's Logic : 5.5 Metatheoretical Results](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/aristotle-logic/#MetRes) : "1. No deduction has two negative premises. 2. No deduction has two particular premises", etc.